Hibernate JPA entities with Join table saves information correctly but when fetching the list is always null
I am new to Hibernate so forgive me for this novice question.
I have 2 entities with many-to-many relationships with a join table, in the mix.
These are the entities
@Table(name = "family")
data class Family(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    val id: Int,
    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(
        name = "family_user",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "family_id")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "user_id")]
    )
    val users: Set<User> = emptySet()
)

@Table(name = "user")
data class User(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id") val id: Int,
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    val firstName: String,

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    val families: Set<Family> = emptySet()
)

After I save the Family using the APIs, I can verify in the db that the join table is correctly updated with user_id and family_id and I can successfully fetch the data from the db using this join query
SELECT u.*, f.id as family_id FROM household.family_user fu  join household.family f on fu.family_id=f.id join household.user u on fu.user_id= u.id where family_id = 2 

But my Family::users and User::families always return empty data.
Is the implementation right? or am I missing something obvious?
